# Mysqldump , Drop database , create database from database list file

Tags: bash, mysql

I have any file with database name each line (database.txt):

```
database1
database2
.....
```

How can I use this file to :

```
$create database
$mysqldump
$drop database


create database from database.txt
$mysqldump database > database  from database.txt
$drop database , from database.txt
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use loop like

```
while read -r db_name 
do 
    create database ${db_name} 
    mysqldump ${db_name} [tbl_name ...]
    drop database ${db_name} 

done< "database.txt"
```